# How to Click Button (input type =hidden) By Perl?

Tags: html, perl, button, onclick

I want to use Perl to click on a button. I get HTML content and then find the button to click. 
But "input type = hidden" when I check the HTML content.

> HTML content:

```
<div class="content freepts_cont">

<input type="hidden" id="network" value="5"/>

<div class="like_notification"></div>
```

> Firebug content:

```
<div class="content freepts_cont">
<input id="network" type="hidden" value="5">
<div class="like_notification"></div>
<div id="site-links-list">
<center>
<div id="L_c3cbf051418f1ec690c445ad843144" class="yt-video-content" style="width: 520px;">
 <div class="likedPagesSingle" style="width:400px;border:1px solid #E8E8E8;padding-top:15px; min-height:250px;">
<center>
<center>
<div class="fb_page_title">
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
<a style="display:block; width:100px; heigt:100px; overflow:hidden;" href="#">
<img style="width:100%; height:auto;" title="Night Thriller" alt="Night Thriller" src="/images/layout/youtube_page_view.png">
</a>
</div>
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin(843144, 'JTJGMiUzQSVFMyVEQyUxNSU5MSU4NCUxMSU3RiVFNyU4OCUyM1clM0QyJUM3JUIwMw==');">
</center>
<div class="mtop10" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<div class="mtop10" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
</div>
</div>
```

I want use Perl to click:
 `<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin(843144, 'JTJGMiUzQSVFMyVEQyUxNSU5MSU4NCUxMSU3RiVFNyU4OCUyM1clM0QyJUM3JUIwMw==');">`

How?

Comment: You need to either reverse engineer the JavaScript and reimplement it in Perl or use a headless browser like Selenium or PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, and in my own experience quite easy to set up and use would be

[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).

I am not entirely certain what exactly you are trying to do - change the value of a hidden input and then submit ? Perhaps the tiny and untested snippet will be of use to you.

If you have more specific questions, I can probably help, but the CPAN docs have so far cleared up any of my questions, so don't dismiss them too quickly ;)

Either way, Mechanize is quite well documented and useful for this task.

Edit: I somehow overlooked the link you gave. This code *should* find it.

Edit2: you might want to try [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#JAVASCRIPT_METHODS), which seems to be able to handle javascript. I would use it, but I am already accustomed to Mechanize. Perhaps others can suggest a better option.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->follow_link( class => 'single_like_button btn3-wrap' );
# alternatively, get the link object, see what you can do with that
my $link = $mech->find_link( class => 'single_like_button btn3-wrap' );
# or, if it is not the only one of class
my @links = $mech->find_links( class => 'single_like_button btn3-wrap' );
# now somehow get the link out of the list
```

This may not work, as it seems the link is not really provided. in that case, try to use click() or click_button(). To be perfectly honest, I will have to point you to the docs there, since I have limited experience with this specific problem, so far getting links and following them was all I needed to do for testing my sites.

Good luck with Mechanize!

Comment: Use WWW::Scripter with same mechanize methods. It runs javascript after you install its plugin sudo cpanm WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript